# How to find Spark's implementation of Dataframe's write method?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using below snippet to write a Spark dataframe to Oracle database. It must be iterating over dataframe's partitions and creating sql insert statements, grouping 10k of them in one batch while writing, creating connection etc).

```
myDF.write
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", jdbcUrl)
      .option("dbtable", "my_schema.my_table")
      .option("user", username)
      .option("password", password)
      .option("batchsize", 10000)
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .save()
```

How do I find the code which is doing so?

If I navigate to write method then I just see below -

```
/**
   * Interface for saving the content of the non-streaming Dataset out into external storage.
   *
   * @group basic
   * @since 1.6.0
   */
  def write: DataFrameWriter[T] = {
    if (isStreaming) {
      logicalPlan.failAnalysis(
        "'write' can not be called on streaming Dataset/DataFrame")
    }
    new DataFrameWriter[T](this)
  }
```

Comment: As you see `write` just returns `DataFrameWriter`. Perhaps `save` method is what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks, yeah it is perhaps `save` method that I am looking for. However, it is not very straightforward to understand how spark is writing dataframe to JDBC as these methods are common for all sources. I wanted to quickly check on how the write to jdbc part is implemented :)

Comment: I think you should look at the implementation of `JdbcRelationProvider`. Also you can read about it [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-JdbcRelationProvider.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. The link you mentioned is really helpful in understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look at the implementation of [JdbcRelationProvider](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcRelationProvider.scala). Also you can read about it [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-JdbcRelationProvider.html).